# Replace/Exclude option when doing global Find/Replace in Intellij/Pycharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I use the case-by-case Replace/Exclude feature frequently in `Intellij`/`Pycharm`.  I thought it applied to Global Find/Replace but maybe I'm misremembering and it's just in a single file?  Here is what it looks like in the latter:

[image]

Instead in the Global Find/Replace (all files) then it looks like below. Notice it has `Replace All` but not the options to step through like in the single-file dialog.

[image]

Is there such an option for Global Find/Replace that I'm not bumping into this time around?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is no direct equivalent of the `[One-by-one] Find/Replace in [this] File`.

The closest is to click on `Open in Find Window` on bottom of the dialog:

[image]

This opens in a bottom Panel. Within that panel we can accept changes *line by line* by hitting <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Or we can skip an entire line by hitting down arrow.

*Note that at the line level it is thus *all or nothing*.  For example in the following screenshot I wanted to *not* replace the *first* instance of `Status` but to go ahead with changing the second . Well that's not possible.  I will have to skip the update for this line, run through all the changes in other lines and then come back to manually update it.

[image]